# Way to access subset of array?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do something in C# that's fairly easy to do in C++.  Specifically, if I have an array of data, I can create a pointer into that data to access a subsection more conveniently.

For example, if I have:

```
unsigned char buffer[1000];
```

and I determine that there's a string at positions 102 to 110 within that array that I need to manipulate a lot, I can do this:

```
unsigned char *strPtr = &buffer[102];
char firstChar = strPtr[0];
```

This saves me from having to add "102" to each array index in subsequent operations.

While I recognize the possibility of unsafe situations when you do something like this, I'm wondering if there is a moral equivalent in C# that would let me create a new reference to a subset of an existing array.

Something like:

```
byte [8] newArray = &buffer[102];
```

That example doesn't actually work or I wouldn't be posting this, but I think it gets the idea of what I want to accomplish across.

Comment: Would you want it to be a copy or modify the original array directly?

Comment: I wouldn't actually be writing back to it, just reading from it.  I would like to avoid copying data.  In fact, I wouldn't be asking if copying data wasn't a tripping point.

Comment: If your concern is just to read from the data, why not just keep an `int offset = 102; buffer[offset + i] ...`? It means you don't need unsafe code to accomplish the task. The `ArraySegment<T>` is definitely an even cleaner approach to do the same. If you are truly trying to avoid the offset calculation for some reason, then you have to use unsafe code.

Comment: Jason, that's exactly the scenario I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the [`ArraySegment<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class which can be used as a wrapper to access segments of an array.  Just provide the array, an offset and the length of the segment and you could use it as if it were the actual array.  You'll get bounds checking and other niceties of using arrays.

```
var buffer = new byte[1000];
var newArray = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 102, 8) as IList<byte> // we have an "array" of byte[8]
var firstChar = newArray[0];
```

---

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/120) however to introduce array slicing.  As like the ArraySegment, slices allow you to create views into arrays (without making copies) and can be used in place of actual arrays.  Hopefully it will make it into a (near) future C# version.

Comment: Isn't the ArraySegment<T> doing what the OP is trying to avoid by getting/changing the intended element of the original error with the use of the offset? I thought that structure worked by adding your index + the internal `_offset` and returning resulting element.

Comment: @JasonW But the technique described in the OP is exactly that, a shortcut for adding a "offset" to the array.

Comment: Seems like he's trying to avoid adding the offset each time he accesses the element. I know the _offset is stored in the struct, but what I wasn't sure about was that if the _offset is used each time the element is accessed (that's what I think he's trying to prevent for whatever reason)

Comment: This looks promising. I'll check it out.

Comment: The whole answer turned out to be:

`byte[] b = (new ArraySegment<byte>(buf, 102, 8) as IList<byte>).ToArray();`

Comment: @MikeFulton: No, don't do that.  The whole point of using the `ArraySegment` class was that you _didn't_ have to copy the elements to a new one (as in C/C++).  That way you could just work with a view of an array.  If you specifically wanted to create a new one, there are other (possibly better) ways to do that.

Comment: @JeffMercado - yeah I figured that out. I didn't realize at first it was going to make a copy of the data.  The docs could be a tad more explicit on that.  Now I'm just using IList<byte> and everything is working as I wanted.